# Prove that $ n^2$ tends to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Definition: A sequence $x_n$ diverges if for each $c\gt0$, there exists some $N$ such that $\forall n \ge N, x_n\ge c$.

I have tried:

Suppose $c\gt 0$, so that $n^2\gt c,\;\text{and}\;  n \gt\sqrt c$

Where do I take it from here? How do I show that there is some $N$ that is greater than $c$? Is there a theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your definition and the proof are poorly written. You should use correct quantifiers to understand what you are doing. The following is a possible better definition and proof.

Definition. A sequence $x_n$ diverges to $+\infty$ if given any number $c$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ one has $x_n \ge c$.

Proof that $x_n = n^2$ diverges to $+\infty$. Given any $c$ the condition $x_n \ge c$ is satisfied if $n^2 \ge c $ i.e. $n \ge \sqrt c$. So if we choose $N\ge \sqrt c$ and $n\ge N$ the condition is satisfied.

The archimedean property is implicitly used: for all $x\in \mathbb R$ there exist $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $N>x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: you have to choose $N$. What about an integer just above $\sqrt{c}$ ?

Comment: Let N = c+1?

Or is there a theorem from which I can follow from?

Induction, perhaps?

Comment: By the archimedian property there is a natural number $N\geq \sqrt{c}$.

Comment: Cheers mate! 
This was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> **Hint**: Take $N$ to be the square root of $c$.

Comment: That was what I did.

I have Sqrt[c] < Sqrt[N] < n

Am I allowed to say N = c+1 or in other words the least integers just above c?
Or would it be a more elegant act to draw a theorem from which one can state that N > c?
Induction, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Take N = c and then done! Now you see that given any integer c > 1, N^2 = c^2 > c.